# Best practice displaying menu and toolbar in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a webapplication where a user can log into his account. When the user is logged in now the sidenav(menu) and toolbar appears. But when the user isn't logged in (maybe he is going to login or registrate) the toolbar and sidenav should be not visible.

What is the best practice to do that in Angular2(version: 2.1.0 and angular/router version: 3.1.0)

I tried to disable the toolbar and sidenav with `ngIf` but It doesn't really work and I think it is not a clean solution.

Then I thought about two `<router-outlet>`. One for the routing when the user is logged in and one when the user is not logged in. Is this the right way to solve my problem? If yes, how does it work?

Here my app.component.html where I define my toolbar, sidenav and the `<router-outlet>`:

```
<md-sidenav-layout class="{{themeService.ActualTheme}}" fullscreen>
    <div *ngIf="menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage !== 'landing' && menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage !== 'register'">
    <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="{{menuToolbarConfigService.setSideNav(sidenav)}}">
        <div>
        <div class="sidenav-header">
            <div class="logo-circle">
                <span class="logo">GT</span>
            </div>
            <span class="user-name">Nico</span>
            <span class="open-tasks">Offene Tasks: 4</span>
        </div>
        <md-list>
            <div [ngClass]="{'highlight': menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage === 'start'}" class="nav-list-item">
                <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon>assignment</md-icon> Taskboard
                </md-list-item>
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="{'highlight': menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage === 'groups'}" class="nav-list-item">
                <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon>group</md-icon> Gruppen
                </md-list-item>
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="{'highlight': menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage === 'user'}" class="nav-list-item">
                <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon>account_circle</md-icon> Benutzer
                </md-list-item>
            </div>
            <div [ngClass]="{'highlight': menuToolbarConfigService.ActualPage === 'user'}" class="nav-list-item">
                <md-list-item>
                    <md-icon>search</md-icon> Taskbrowser
                </md-list-item>
            </div>
        </md-list>
        </div>
    </md-sidenav>
    </div>

    <md-toolbar color="primary">
        <span *ngIf="menuToolbarConfigService.ShowMenuIcon" (click)="sidenav.open();" class="menu-icon"><md-icon>menu</md-icon></span>
        <span class="app-title">GroupTasking</span>

        <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
        <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>

    </md-toolbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</md-sidenav-layout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: *ngIf is the right solution, when you are using ngIf what kind of problem are facing?. maintain one service that helps you too check either usr logged in or not? in ngIf check that user is login than display sidebar or not logged in do not display sidebar. ngIf why is perfect solution bcz ngIf completely remove html from DOM if it is false and vise versa.

Comment: yes this was always my solution for this problem but I just thought its not the best practice

Comment: than you can put router-out let under ngIf, based on user login status u can display router-outlet.

Comment: ok I thought there is a way to have multiple router-outlet without using ngIf, maybe give the outlets different names

Comment: Yes, we can do that also.

Comment: The best to do that is using ngIf with public services boolean methods, then your not specified problems will end.